# Adding + sign to a table, revealing more rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, html-table

**Problem :** I'm completely new to front end development. I have managed to make a table with some data about university courses using JSONP and AJAX. However, I need to add a new column to the start of each row defaulting to a + sign. When this is clicked, a new set of data describing all the students on the course opens up, and the + becomes a - . I cant yet see the best way to do this. Any advice?

**Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="json-jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/getCourses.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "courses",
    success: function( data ) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
  });
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.courses.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data.courses[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.courseName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.start + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.end + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lecturerName + "</td>"));
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to change the contents of your button, or simply toggle a class on it and let css change the visual display.
Apply a common class to the elements for event binding selector simplification.

I would add a data attribute containing the course identifier that is needed to make next request for student data.

```
function drawRow(rowData) {
    var button='<anyElement data-courseId="'+ rowData.id +'" class="data-button">+</anyElement>';
    var row = $("<tr />")
    row.append('<td>'+button+'</td>');/* no need to wrap html in "$()" */

    /* append other cells*/

    /* do append to DOM after row created , makes for less DOM insertions*/
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
}
```

Then within your ready handler add an event handler for the buttons. Within an event handler `this` refers to current instance.

```
$("#dataTable").on('click', '.data-button',function(){

    /* text change method */
    $(this).text(function( _ , currText){
         return currText === '+' ? '-' : '+';
    });

     /* class change */
     $(this).toggleClass('active');

    /* get data */

     var id= $(this).data('courseId');
     /* make api call based on id*/

})
```

Comment: This looks great. Very basic beginner's question for you ... where to I put the 2nd bit of code? What is the ready handler?

Comment: Ah, of course! I KNEW that! Right, Ive now got a + and - toggling. Now I need to make the new data appear... Mmmm

Comment: So now Im trying to work out how to get the data. The data is already here in the 'data' object I called at the start. Itrs just deeper in the hierarchy of data. However, I'm struggling to access the data object at the moment due to my inexperience.

Comment: var id= $(this).data('courseId'); isn't working. Data and id are both blank. Do you know why?

Comment: depends on what your data looks like , i only assumed a property `id`

Comment: The start of the data looks like this .... courses({
  "courses": [
      {
 "id": "1", "

Comment: However, the issue is that data is blank at this point in the code. Don't I need to save it somewhere so it can be accessed at this point, or does javascript not work like that?

Comment: to be honest, comments aren't the best way to start a whole new question about what to do with data once button selected since it wasn't part of original question

Comment: Ok. I guess I meant to include getting the data as part of the original question, but I'm happy to split it up into 2 questions if I continue to struggle! Green tick coming your way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58103/discussion-between-andy-a-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

I add some codes which can do the function to covert + to - part.

Next part is just the same as what you did in previous codes.

Is it helping you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script src="json-jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/getCourses.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "courses",
    success: function( data ) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
  });
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.courses.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data.courses[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    var $td = $("<td class='clickTd'>+</td>")
        .on('click', tdClickEvent);
    row.append($td);
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.courseName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.start + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.end + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lecturerName + "</td>"));

    $("#dataTable").append(row);
}

function tdClickEvent(){
    $(this).text('-');
    /*
    the student show function
    */
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This certainly looks interesting. Im currently getting "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function" though. Also, I presume 'calss' should say 'class'?

Comment: @AndyA just noticed you are using old version of jQuery (1.5) ..`$.on()` didn't exist then

Comment: @charlietfl What is the latest version of jQuery? Do I just change the following line ... ? - <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

Comment: @AndyA yes, can change version in that script tag , try `1.11.1` .

Comment: oh ! @AndyA thanks for your correction, or you can use $(...).click(),  if your version is old

Answer (score 0):

if You can restructure your table a little, then this might just help you :

the js fiddle :
**http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/8bm5T/1/**

```
$("#mainTable").on("click", ".collapse", function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt === "+") {
        $(this).parent().next().show();
        $(this).text("-");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next().hide();
        $(this).text("+");
    }
});
```